# how to initialise ViewModel in createFragment of FragmentStateAdapter?

Tags: android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-lifecycle

I have a `ExerciseDetailFragment` that contains an `ExerciseFragmentStatePagerAdapter` to show a bunch of `SupportUsFragmentCard`. These cards can be swiped horizontally by the user.

[image]

In my `ExerciseFragmentStatePagerAdapter` I have the following code:

```
fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    val exercise = exercises[position]
    val card = SupportUsFragmentCard()
    card.setExercise(exercise) <---- this is my question/problem
    return card
}
```

As you can see the pager adapter just instantiates the `SupportUsFragmentCard` and for this the `exercise` needs to be passed along (the card displays some exercise information) via the `setExercise`.

The SupportUsFragmentCard looks like this:

```
open class SupportUsFragmentCard : RootFragment() {
    ...
    val viewModel: SupportUsViewModel by viewModels()
    ...

    fun setExercise(exercise: Exercise?) {
        viewModel.setExercise(exercise) <---- passes on the exercise to the viewModel
    }
```

It’s implementation passes along the `exercise` to the underlying `viewModel`. Which in its turn encapsulates this into a `LiveData` (on which the `SupportUsFragmentPlain` has observers but I omitted this code as its not the issue):

```
class SupportUsViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    //interface to the view
    fun getExercise(): LiveData<Exercise?> = exercise
    fun setExercise(execise: Exercise?) {
        exercise.value = execise. <--- updates the Livedata object
    }

    //underlying live data mutable values
    private val exercise = MutableLiveData<Exercise?>(null)
}
```

When this code is executed, it crashes with exception:

> IllegalStateException: Can't access ViewModels from detached fragment

I think because the `createFragment` ends up updating the `viewModel` without actually already being on screen. I also feel that this way of working does not respect the MVVM architecture.

What is the correct way in this scenario, using MVVM and LiveData to initialise the `SupportUsViewModel` with an `Exercise` in the `ExerciseFragmentStatePagerAdapter`'s `createFragment` function?

Comment: Ran into the same problem. I feel like the best way with respect to MVVM architecture would be to pass ExerciseRepository  (or whatever your repository is) upon initializing SupportUsViewModel in the constructor then loading the Exercise directly from the DataSource into your SupportUsViewModel instead of passing it to the fragment. You can just pass an ID in a bundle for example, telling it which Exercise to load.